# How to create image movement with functionality?

Tags: android, image, drag

I'm trying to create something like the unlock activity of the android, where you drag the lock image outside of the circle to unlock the phone. I want to drag an image and to start an activity when it reaches a certain position. I tried doing it with a canvas but it turned out to paint other parts of my screen. So I tried using the following snippet where I found in another post here:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_touch_ball);



    windowwidth = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
    windowheight = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
    final ImageView balls = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ball);

    balls.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                        LayoutParams layoutParams = (LayoutParams) balls.getLayoutParams();
                        switch(event.getAction())
                        {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:   
                                                        break;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                                                        int x_cord = (int)event.getRawX();
                                                        int y_cord = (int)event.getRawY();

                                                        if(x_cord>windowwidth){x_cord=windowwidth;}
                                                        if(y_cord>windowheight){y_cord=windowheight;}

                                                        layoutParams.leftMargin = x_cord;
                                                        layoutParams.topMargin = y_cord;

                                                        balls.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                                                        break;
                        default:
                                                        break;
                        }
                            return true;
                    }
            });
}
```

But this also doesn't work so well, since when I touch the image it changes its size and also doesn't move smoothly on the screen.

Do you know how can I start an activity, lets say when I drag an image from the bottom of the screen to the top?

Answer (score 0):

This is because of following line

```
layoutParams.leftMargin = x_cord;
layoutParams.topMargin = y_cord;
balls.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

If you are setting margins, according to that balls will move.

Comment: so what do you suggest? how can I make it better?